# How can I show 4 dates in a calendar view at the same time?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I have 4 dates that I want to show in a calendar view.

Heres my actual code:

```
  <record id="proevents_calendar_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">proevents.calendar</field>
        <field name="model">proevent.events</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
               <calendar  string="Eventos" color="eventdesc" date_start="eventdatein" date_stop="eventdateout" >
                <field name="eventdesc"/>
               </calendar>

                <calendar  string="Montajes" color="eventdesc" date_start="setupdatein" date_stop="setupdateout" >
                <field name="eventdesc"/>
                </calendar>
        </field>
    </record>
```

This code give me an error. I believe it is because i cant create two calendars at the same time but how could I show the 4 dates in a single view?

My variables are: eventdatein,eventdateout,setupdatein,setupdateout

Answer (score 2):

You can't: the Calendar view supports only one date field.
For the effect you want you need four event records.

I suggest this design:

- add to `proevents.events` a child model (one-to-many relation), `proevents.events.date`, to store the date records you need, and expected to have four rows.
- have the calendar view use `proevents.events.date`.

Depending on your specific use case, you might need to add some logic to ensure that the four date lines are added for each event.

*Note: your model should be named in singular and with the underlying main module as the first word: `event.provevent`.*

Comment: Hello Daniel,  can you explain how can do that task.